# Scala Akka SBT error 'set current project in build file'

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I'm trying to create a new sbt akka scala project called 'biddingagent'.

Steps I followed:

- I created a folder 'biddingagent'.
- Then ran 'cd biddingagent' in command terminal
- Then I ran the command `sbt new akka/akka-scala-seed.g8` in the terminal.
- But I keep getting the error below.
  What could be the problem? I'm I doing it right. What is the best way to do this.
  Thanks in advance!

```
D:\Studio\Work\Eskimi\biddingagent>sbt new akka/akka-scala-seed.g8
[info] set current project to biddingagent (in build file:/D:/Studio/Work/Eskimi/biddingagent/)
[warn] Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt-giter8-resolver/sbt-giter8-resolver_2.12/0.13.1/sbt-giter8-resolver_2.12-0.13.1.pom

[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt.sbt-giter8-resolver#sbt-giter8-resolver_2.12;0.13.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

[error] Retrieval of org.scala-sbt.sbt-giter8-resolver:sbt-giter8-resolver:0.13.1 failed.
```

Comment: Have you already setup other SBT or Maven projects? Seems you don't have access to `repo1.maven.org`, could it be a network issue (proxy, VPN...)?

Comment: No. I haven't. I'm a novice. Could you please give me a simple step by step on doing this.

Comment: Did you check if you have access to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt-giter8-resolver/sbt-giter8-resolver_2.12/0.13.1/ from your browser then your console?

Comment: It seems to work fine in a browser.

Comment: I suggest you go to this [official page](https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=akka) for downloading an akka template project that suites your needs, and start from there.